# Modifying JSON Key Value Pairs In Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have incoming JSON rows of data like,

```
{"signalName": "IU_BATT_ParkAssist", "msgId": 2268, "epoch": 1582322746, "usec": 376360, "vlan": "-1", "msgName": "EBS_Frame12", "vin": "000004", "value": 14.171869, "timestamp": 1582322746376}
```

I want the output to be modified to produce,

```
{"IU_BATT_ParkAssist":14.171869, "msgId": 2268, "epoch": 1582322746, "usec": 376360, "vlan": "-1", "msgName": "EBS_Frame12", "vin": "000004", "timestamp": 1582322746376}
```

The signalName and value keys were combined to make one new **key:value pair** with the key being the signalName and the value being the value field, **"IU_BATT_ParkAssist":14.171869** along with the other original key, value pairs.

How can I achieve this in Nifi given that the signalName field will be dynamically changing in each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Try with below spec:`**

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@(1,value)": "@(2,signalName)",
      "*": "&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "signalName": "",
      "value": ""
    }
  }
]
```

In **shift** operation we are combining **`signalName and value`**.

In **remove** operation we are removing **`signalName and value`** from our `json` data.

**`Output:`**

```
{
  "IU_BATT_ParkAssist" : 14.171869,
  "msgId" : 2268,
  "epoch" : 1582322746,
  "usec" : 376360,
  "vlan" : "-1",
  "msgName" : "EBS_Frame12",
  "vin" : "000004",
  "timestamp" : 1582322746376
}
```